# Simplify $\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot1}{(2n)(2n-2)\cdots 4 \cdot2 }$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Wolfram alphas step by step function has failed me.

My try:

$\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\dotsm3\cdot1}{(2n)(2n-2)\dotsm 4 \cdot\cdot2 } $

$ 
= \frac{\prod_{m=1}^{n} 2n-(2m+1)}{\prod_{m=1}^{n} 2n-(2m)} 
=\prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{2n-(2m+1)}{2n-(2m)} $

$ 
= \prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{2n-2m}{2n-2m}-\frac{1}{2n-2m}
=-n \cdot \prod_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2n-2m}
= -n \cdot \frac{1}{(2n)(2n-2)\dotsm4\cdot2} = wrong$

The correct solution would be:

$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What is $k$ in the final expression?

Comment: The question would be: Where is my mistake and regarding the k, it was a mistake of mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the missing products in the numerator to have $$\frac{(2n)!}{\left[(2n)(2n-2)\ldots2 \right]^2}$$

And factoring the denominator yields

$$\frac{(2n)!}{\left[ \left[(2n)\right]\left[2(n-1)\right]\ldots\left[2\times2\right]\left[2\times1\right]\right]^2}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{(2n)!}{\left[2^nn! \right]^2}$$

Comment: You were the first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot1}{(2n)\cdot(2n-2)\cdots2}=\frac{\color{red}{(2n)}(2n-1)\color{red}{(2n-2)}(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot\color{red}{2}\cdot 1}{(2n)^{\color{red}{2}}\cdot(2n-2)^{\color{red}{2}}\cdots 2^{\color{red}{2}}}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
\begin{align}
1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1) = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1) (2n)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n} n!}
\end{align}
and $2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n) = 2^{n} n!$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2n)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^{2}} = \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^{n}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

First note that the denominator can be written as $2^n\cdot n!$. So we multiply your original expression by $1=\frac{2n\cdot(2n-2)\cdots 2 }{2^n\cdot n!}$ $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!n!}=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the way, your products should all go from $0$ to $n-1$, not $1$ to $n$, but that isn’t your main mistake.

The bigger mistake was to write $$\prod \frac{2n-2m}{2n-2m}-\frac{1}{2n-2m}
=-n \cdot \prod \frac{1}{2n-2m}\text{.  (This is wrong.)}$$

In fact,

$$\prod \left(\frac{2n-2m}{2n-2m}-\frac{1}{2n-2m}\right)= \prod\left(1-\frac{1}{2n-2m}\right),$$

which doesn’t help so much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $${(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot 1\over (2n)(2n-2)\cdots4\cdot 2}.$$ Every term in the denominator is divisible by $2$. So we can factor a $2^n$ out of the denominator for each of the $n$ terms. The remaining terms give us $n!$. Thus we have $${(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1\over 2^nn!}.$$ We see that the numerator is missing all of the even terms. So we will multiply the numerator and denominator by $(2n)(2n-2)\cdots 4\cdot 2$. Thus we have $${(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1\over 2^nn!(2n)(2n-2)\cdots4\cdot 2}.$$ Since $(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=(2n!)$ and $(2n)(2n-2)\cdots 4\cdot 2=2^nn!$ we have $${(2n!)\over 2^{2n}(n!)^2}.$$